# Как лучше построить предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

"Топот копыт коней всадников". Мне не нравится это предложение: "копыт коней всадников..." — слишком много существительных подряд. Но как сказать иначе, придумать не могу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, "кони всадников" явно перехлёст. Всадник не на коне - уже не всадник. Неужели так важно, чьи это были кони. Если оставить "топот коней" - тоже понятно, что они топают копытами. Нужен, действительно, контекст, чтобы правильно построить фразу.

Comment: А с другой стороны, сказать "топот копыт всадников" тоже смешно: выходит, что копыта у всадников, а не у коней)))

Answer (score 1):

Дело не в существительных. Это т.н. многократный родительный падеж, его действительно стоит избегать по стилистическим рекомендациям.

В данном случае я не вижу необходимости в "конях всадников". Контекст можно посмотреть, почему вдруг так важно упомянуть и тех и других?

Comment: Вывеска (реальная) "Отдел по работе с молодежью аппарата главы администрации города Казани". У-ф-ф. Не сразу поймешь, что к чему!

Comment: >Вывеска (реальная) "Отдел по работе с молодежью аппарата главы администрации города Казани". У-ф-ф. Не сразу поймешь, что к чему!

Получается, что отдел работает только с молодёжью, входящей в аппарат главы администрации.)))

Comment: Это бы еще ничего... "Молодежь аппарата главы" - вот где соль-то!
Типа аппарат это то, чем молодежь делают.